# How to see keyframe in After Effect

Tags: adobe-after-effects, video

I have opened an old project and in the timline i can see [image: "lines"] and not single key frame.
How can i see the single keyframe?

Comment: 1. How long is the timeline?
2. Are there ANY keyframes?
3. Please send a screenshot with whole panel.

Comment: is long 2/3 seconds more or less, i was doing test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You expand the layer's properties by clicking the arrow at the far left or the layer...

> [image]
>   <sub>Image from: https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/layer-properties.html#layer_properties_in_the_timeline_panel</sub>

There are also a few useful shortcuts for doing so – the most useful being...

- <kbd>U</kbd>, which shows any properties that have keyframes
- <kbd>U</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>, which shows any properties modified from their default

It's all explain in the Adobe help here:

- [After Effects Support – Layer properties in the Timeline panel](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/layer-properties.html#show_or_hide_properties_in_the_timeline_panel)